# UIButton does not move if called after addSubView

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

So I am trying to move a `UIButton` after it is clicked.

The `_addMoreFields` method is called after the button is clicked.

`_addMoreFieldBtn` is a global `UIButton`. When I click it nothing happens.

The strange part is if I comment out the `addSubView` code then the button moves.

If I keep that code the button doesn't move.

Any Ideas?

```
-(void)movePlusButton {
    NSLog(@"Moving button");
    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    _addMoreFieldsBtn.center = CGPointMake(30,30);
    [UIButton commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)addMoreFields:(id)sender {

    CGRect currentBtnFrame = [(UIButton *)sender frame];
    CGPoint org = currentBtnFrame.origin;

    UILabel *whoWasIn = [[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, org.y, 85, 21)];
    whoWasIn.text = @"test";

    UITextField *whoWasInField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(59, whoWasIn.frame.origin.y+40, 202, 30)];
    whoWasInField.placeholder = @"test2";

    UILabel *with = [[UILabel alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(136, whoWasInField.frame.origin.y+40, 49, 21)];
    with.text = @"with";
    whoWasInField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    UITextField *withField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(59, with.frame.origin.y+40, 202, 30)];
    withField.placeholder = @"test3";
    withField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    [_homeView addSubview:whoWasIn];
    [_homeView addSubview:with];
    [_homeView addSubview:whoWasInField];
    [_homeView addSubview:withField];

    [self movePlusButton];
}
```

NOTE: I also tried changing the frame but I get the same issue. It starts animating from the new location I put to the existing spot.

Comment: even if i put the movePlusButton method before the addSubViews it still doesnt work. Very confused here

Comment: Is MovePlusButton getting called?

Comment: How do you set up your `_addMoreFieldsBtn`? Paste code showing the alloc/init/addsubview.

Comment: @nullp01nter property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addMoreFieldsBtn;

Comment: I created an empty project, inserted your code, added a small plus button (`addMoreFieldsBtn`) and an empty view (`homeView`). I tested it in the simulator and the button jumped to position (30, 30) as expected. I suggest you also create an empty test project and see if it works for you.

Comment: So the funny thing is i noticed when i do it now that it starts animating from the new frame location and comes back the orginal location as if i was telling it to start transitioning it from that frame to my existing frame. Im confused :-)

Comment: @nullp01nter The difference between mine and yours is that my XIB has a view in the main window and then i create another view in that xib and that is where the button and labels are. That is the homeView. The  viewcontrollers view is the other view not homeview.

Comment: @nullp01nter for the heck of it i created a sample app just with one xib, one view and the button and it still does the same thing. Im not sure what app you created but it doesnt work for me. I am on IOS6.

Comment: @ScootaP I bet this works if you turn off Autolayout.  Click on one of your views in your Storyboard, and in the File Inspector pane, uncheck "Autolayout."  Does that fix it?

Comment: @JShapiro you mean Auto resize subviews?

Comment: @JShapiro you are the man!! that worked. I found the auto layout checkbox. Why was that the issue? what does that do?

Comment: @ScootaP OK, I posted an answer... let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that new projects in iOS 6 / Xcode 4.5 have "Autolayout" enabled by default.  Autolayout is a replacement for "Springs and Struts" (but it only works iOS 6).  This feature adds constraints to a view which take precedence over the move you were attempting in your code.

So there are three possible fixes to this:

1) Create new constraints on the button programmatically. Autolayout is pretty powerful and flexible... especially if you are trying to support the footprint of both the iPhone 5 and earlier models.  You can find more info on how to do this by checking out the WWDC video: [Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)

2) Don't use Autolayout.  Select a view in your Storyboard, and in the File Inspector, uncheck "Use Autolayout."

3) Create IBOutlets for each of the constraints on the button.  Then before you move the button, remove those constraints:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addMoreFieldsBtn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *hConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *vConstraint;
- (IBAction)addMoreFields:(id)sender;
@end
```

and...

```
-(void)movePlusButton {
    NSLog(@"Moving button");
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.hConstraint];
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.vConstraint];
    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    _addMoreFieldsBtn.center = CGPointMake(30,30);
    [UIButton commitAnimations];
}
```

(the actual view you need to call `removeConstraints:` on is the parent view of the button, which may or may not be self.view).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that whats happening is that your subview is coming onto to screen first, and therefore taking precedence, and then once the subview is removed, the button would move, if you change the code:

```
[_homeView addSubview:whoWasIn];
[_homeView addSubview:with];
[_homeView addSubview:whoWasInField];
[_homeView addSubview:withField];

[self movePlusButton];
```

}// move the [self movePlusButton]; up 6 lines of code, or make it first line

```
[self movePlusButton];
[_homeView addSubview:whoWasIn];
[_homeView addSubview:with];
[_homeView addSubview:whoWasInField];
[_homeView addSubview:withField];
```

This should solve all of your problems

:)

Comment: Did you test this code with Autolayout enabled?  I tried and it didn't work for me.