# Button not moving on my interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm making an app and i'm trying to get a button to move to certain coordinates depending on the screen size of the phone (4, 4S, 5, etc). I have correct syntax but the button will not move at all. Here is the part of my .m ViewController file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"scale")])
    {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] < 1.1) {
            CGRect frame = done.frame;
            frame.origin.x = 129; //New x coordinate
            frame.origin.y = 401; //New y coordinate
            done.frame = frame;
            [done setNeedsDisplay];
            NSLog(@"Standard Resolution");
        }
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] > 1.9) {
            NSLog(@"High Defenition Resolution");
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

The `NSLog` is triggering in the console saying `Standard Resolution`, but the button doesn't move from where I placed it in the XIB file. This may be a small stupid mistake but hopefully you can help me anyways.

P.S. Yes, I did link my `IBOutlet` to the button.

Comment: Just setting the frame to new coordinates won't force the button to move. You should call [done setNeedsDisplay] after done.frame = frame; to let it know that you have made changes and it needs to be redrawn. Although I'm not 100% sure on this, since I don't work with XIB files. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I added it but unfortunately it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I also updated my post with that added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you started this project in iOS 6 / Xcode 4.5, Autolayout will be on by default.  See my post on this topic here: [UIButton does not move if called after addSubView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925698/uibutton-does-not-move-if-called-after-addsubview/13080365#13080365)